# PostGreSQL DB - phpPgAdmin using XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, postgresql

I have installed PostgreSQL Database in Linux server system. XAMPP is installed on my local system. I have followed the steps in [install phpPgAdmin](http://practicalfoss.blogspot.in/2008/09/how-to-install-postgresql-and.html) .

But I still could not access the phpPgAdmin page using XAMPP.

(I am not clear about to define my remote system's configuration where I have installed postgrSQL database.)

Comment: Previously posted to http://stackoverflow.com/q/27743243/398670 where user was advised to come here.

Comment: If you're using Linux, why are you using some external packaged stack like this "XAMPP" instead of just installing the packaged PHP, Apache and PostgreSQL from your Linux distribution? These third party bundles tend, in my experience, to be a recipe for ongoing problems and upgrade nightmares. They can be OK for development, but even then I'd avoid them. (Also, which "Linux"? There are quite a few. Distro/version please.)